# Using keys in StoreModule.forRoot and keeping the selector scoped to only state

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using the property key 'auth' to scope the reducer in the StoreModule.forRoot setting so I can add other reducers in the future.

But this seems to conflict with my selectors.

**./app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      // here is a 'auth' key 
      auth: authStateReducer,
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]),
    //...
```

**./auth.state.ts**

```js
export interface AuthState {
  token: string;
}
```

**./auth.selectors.ts**

```js
export const selectToken = (state: AuthState) => state.token;
```

**./auth.guard.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AuthState>,
  ) {}

  this.store.select(selectToken)
      .subscribe((token) => {
        console.log(token) // logs undefined
      });
}
```

When I adjust the store to `private store: Store<{ auth: AuthState }>,`, and then the selector to: `export const selectToken = ({ auth: state }) => state.token;` it does work.

However, It seems strange that my selector has knowledge of some setting in app.module.ts.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select the `auth`, then you can select the state from the `auth` slice.
To select the top-level state, use `createFeatureSelector`.

```js
const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');
export const selectToken = createSelector(selectAuthState, (state) => state.token);
```

Comment: I understand now, and this lead me to: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#selecting-feature-states. Eventually I've implemented a createFeature method: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/feature-creators#using-feature-creator. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.